# How to keep an iFrame from autoplaying when hitting the back button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, youtube

I currently have a webpage with an embed youtube video and image overlay that functions as the "play button." I use JavaScript to play the embed video and hide the image once a user clicks on the image overlay. As far as I know, the only way to do that is to add "&autoplay=1" to the url of the youtube video.

Additionally, I have a form on the webpage that the user can submit to send us information. If the form is submitted correctly, it takes the user to a "thank you" page. The issue lies when the user hits the back button from the thank you page. Since I have added "&autoplay=1" to the iFrame, the video continues to play. I've tried resetting the iFrame src by echoing JavaScript in the else part of the if/else statement that handles the form. Also, I'm not entirely sure about this, but I think the back button fires the .click() method, so I'm not sure how I would prevent against this if it treats everything like a button click. I've been stuck on this for quite some time, and would appreciate some possible direction. I'm also starting to believe what I want to achieve may not be entirely possible.

Relevant code:

```
<?PHP
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if($error) { 
            // handle form error
        }
        else {
            // mails the form
            header("location:http://mywebsite.com/thank-you");
        }
    }
?>

<html>
    <body>
        <div id="video-thumbnail">
            <img id="video-image" src="norman.png" class="video-image" alt=""/> 
            <iframe id="video-embed" class="video-embed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ?rel=0&color=white&controls=1&loop=1&showinfo=0" s8011508427261248624="true" replaced="true" ></iframe>
        </div>

       <script>
           (function($){
               $(document).ready( function(){
                   $(".video-image").click(function(){
                   $(".video-embed").css({"opacity":"1","display":"block"});
                   $(".video-embed")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
                   $(this).unbind("click");
                   });
               } );
           })(jQuery)
       </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my own question, with the help of gaetanoM. His answer was fine, it was just missing one line needed to reset the iFrame src at the start of the function to get rid of "&autoplay=1"

```
var backButtonPressed = false;

$(function () {
   $(".video-embed")[0].src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ?rel=0&color=white&controls=1&loop=1&showinfo=0";
   if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {

   window.history.pushState('forward', null, './#forward');

   $(window).on('popstate', function () {
     backButtonPressed = true;
   });
 }

$(".video-image").click(function () {
    $(".video-embed").css({"opacity": "1", "display": "block"});

    // test if back button pressed
    if (backButtonPressed == false) {
      $(".video-embed")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
    }
    $(this).unbind("click");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may detect if back button has been pressed: if so do not set autoplay to your video.

```js
var backButtonPressed = false;

$(function () {
  if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {

    window.history.pushState('forward', null, './#forward');

    $(window).on('popstate', function () {
      backButtonPressed = true;
    });
  }

  $(".video-image").click(function () {
    $(".video-embed").css({"opacity": "1", "display": "block"});

    // test if back button pressed
    if (backButtonPressed == false) {
      $(".video-embed")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
    }
    $(this).unbind("click");
  });
});
```

Comment: I understand the logic behind this and I was searching for something that might attempt to do this; however, this isn't working. I think it's because the autoplay has already been added to the iFrame on an initial click, so even when backButtonPressed == true, &autoplay=1 has already been added to the iFrame on the first click. The back button doesn't seem to refresh/reload anything.